# Turning an array of jquery objects into a jquery set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to know how to convert an array of jquery objects to jquery object.

Actually, with `find` of `jQuery` I retrieve several elements, `find` returns a `jQuery` object on which I apply `jQuery` method such as `clone`, `css` ...

In my case, my elements being retrived, I need to remove duplicates. The I did it, my elements now are in an array and not in a `jQuery` object anymore.

How do I turn an array of `jQuery` objects into a `jQuery` object?

Below is my code:

```
  var $enfants = $('#parent').find('option.enfant');
  var keys = [];
  var values = [];

  $.each($enfants, function(i, e) {
      if (-1 !== $.inArray($(e).val(), keys) ) {
          keys.push($(e).val());
          values.push($(e));
      }
  });

  // This lasts 1ms
  // $enfants.clone().appendTo($('#inconnu'));

  // This lasts 14ms
  // $.each(values, function(i, e) {
  //     $(e).clone().appendTo($('#inconnu'));
  // });
```

Hope it's clear

**UPDATE1**

The code above works well but slower than without removing duplicates

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your code? `values` is now an array of jquery objects, which, in effect, is what I think you want.

Comment: Try with `values.push(e);`

Comment: @Ted: before I didn't remove duplicates, so it was really fast when applying `clone` on the jquery set, but now that I've got to remove duplicates, I must use `each` and apply `clone` on each element which is much slower. It'd be great if I could apply `clone` on my final array (after turning it into jquery object)

Comment: no reason to expect that filtering duplicates won't take time, but appending individually can be imrpoved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, since the `values` array is already 'unique'.
Note the change of pushing `e` instead of `$(e)` into `values`

```
var $enfants = $('#parent').find('option.enfant');
var keys = [];
var values = [];

$.each($enfants, function(i, e) {
      if (-1 !== $.inArray($(e).val(), keys) ) {
          keys.push($(e).val());
          values.push(e);
      }
  });

  $(values).clone().appendTo($('#inconnu'));
```

Comment: (I get that, `values` is a bit of a misdirecting name)

Comment: Hey don't blame the variable's name!! :P, works like a charm thx

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter()` and keep them in jQuery object from the start and do everything in one loop

```
$enfants.filter(function(){
      if (-1 !== $.inArray(this.value, keys) ){
          keys.push(this.value);
          return true;
      }
}).clone().appendTo($('#inconnu'));
```